# Fibonacci sequence formula not working

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, formatting, fibonacci

Please see image below for my references.
The first column just gives us the row numbers
2nd column is the Fibonacci sequence, just adding the previous 2 to get the new row
3rd column should be the quotient of last row b divided by previous a value

It works up until the 4th iteration where the fraction should be:
1.6, but it is 1.0000000 from then on
3rd col should be

```
0
1
2
1.66666666667
1.6
1.625 etc etc.
```

But it is doing

```
0
1
2
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000
1.0000 etc.
```

What is wrong with my code? It should work but isn't. Here is python 3 code:

```
a, b = 0, 1
num = 1
i = 1
f= 0

#loop
for i in range(1, 101):
   #use if to avoid divide by zero initially because a is 0
   if a >= 1:
      f = b / a

   #print 3 column of 3 different numbers   
   print ('{0:4d} {1:20d} {2:1.14f}'.format(i, b, f) )
   i = i + 1 
   a,b = b, a+b
```

[image: output]

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're running this on Python 3? Because in Python 2 I know what the problem would be. Try adding `print 1` (exactly like that, no parentheses) and see if it throws a syntax error.

Comment: I had 3 installed but it was running 2 by default. I forgot about that. So im accepting @LexScarisbrick's answer since it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 2, change the line:

```
f = b / a
```

into

```
f = float(b) / float(a)
```

Are you sure you're using Python 3?  What does `python -V` report?

Comment: this worked for me, so it looks like I was running 2.7.6 because I just used the command python. I forgot i have to run python3 in order to use that. So im giving you the answer for the python 2 solution, which works. Just curious what would the solution be for Python3? python -v returns a lotttttt of stuff so I will skip that as i have the solution.

Comment: It should just work in Python 3 without the `float()` change.  For getting the Python version, make sure to use an uppercase vee: `python -V`